# passing value between 2 angular module in one page

Tags: angularjs

I had created multiple modules in a page and make it nested such as

```
module A{
    module B{
     .....
    }
}
```

izit possible passing value from module A to module B? I refer to this website http://www.simplygoodcode.com/ to create multiple modules in one page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify module A as a dependency of module b.

e.g.

```
var moduleA = angular.module('module-a', []);
// ...
var moduleB = angular.module('module-b', ['module-a']);
```